# not able to build gradle project because javaml depandency failure

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, sourceforge

I Have a gradle Java project running on eclipse which directly uses the Javaml Library, However each time I try to compile the project using `gradle clean build` at the project's root folder i get the following error:

```
 Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find net.sourceforge:javaml:0.1.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/javaml/0.1.5/javaml-0.1.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/javaml/0.1.5/javaml-0.1.5.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
```

The code for my build.Gradle and dependencies are as follows :

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
}
allprojects {apply plugin: 'idea'}
//and standard one
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
docker {
        name "hig"
        dockerfile file('src/docker/Dockerfile')
        copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*","app.jar")
        buildArgs(['JAR_FILE' : "app.jar"])
}
dependencies {
    //compile project(':shared')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ujmp/ujmp-core
    compile group: 'org.ujmp', name: 'ujmp-core', version: '0.3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datumbox/lpsolve
    compile group: 'com.datumbox', name: 'lpsolve', version: '5.5.2.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.7.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge/javaml
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge', name: 'javaml', version: '0.1.5'


}
```

Does anyone know why java ml dependency is not being recognized? 
Note: I visited the maven repository website and javaml is not there 
Note2: I failed to get the dependency locally as well

Answer (score 0):

Under the mvnrepository page there is the provider repos tab.
Add http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/ to build config.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    name "ICM"
    url "http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/"
  }
}
```